# Tax exempt (EEE) options for tax saving in India

Tags: india, tax-free-savings

I'm looking for any tax saving options, which should be completely tax exempt (tax free at source, interest and withdrawal), similar to PPF.

I have PPF account, and I'm not considering PPF for saving all of my savings for the longer lock in period. 
Right now, I'm more comfortable with a 1-5 years time frame.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from PPF, there are no investment that offer EEE. Of course EPF offered by employers also offers same.